# Is there any way to redeem Nitro gifts automatically with discord.py (self-bot)?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to know how to claim Discord Nitro automatically.

```
import discord

token = 'mytoken'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged In!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content.startwith("discord.gift/" + 13):
        #example to claim if there are option
    else:
        print("Invalid Code!")

client.run(token, bot=False)
```

Please help me if you know anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's very possible and quite easy to do so, as the other people have already mentioned. This can get your account disabled so do it at your own risk.
So, let's get into it;
Making one with python is a stupid idea because most nitro  "snipers" have to be fast, since there could always be competition. I recommend getting into node js and making a self-bot with that or a nitrosniper etc. Node JS if by far the fastest if you have a method for client injection, but let's be real. I'll write some python pseudo code for you, it should be quite easy to understand:

```
import discord
import requests
import json

token = 'token'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
print('Online')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
      if message.content.startwith("discord.gift/" + 13):
         """
         make it store the code after the discord.gift/ part, but note most 
         gifts come in the https://discord.gift/ format, you should either use 
         regex for this opertaion or just set two variables so if the message 
         content includes https and discord.gift it stores it as a different 
         variable.
         """
         redeemheaders = {
         'Authorization': token, #dont replace this.
         'content-type': 'application/json',
         'payment_source_id': 'null'
         }
         r = requests.post('https://ptb.discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/'+ codevariable + '/redeem', headers=redeemheaders)
         r = r.text.json()
         print(r)


client.run(token, bot=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not something that Discord's API exposes.
Also, self-bots on [user accounts](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#bot-vs-user-accounts) [are forbidden now](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-) and you're liable to get your account terminated, especially for purposes like this.